# How to Make If...Else Work Using Eval Within ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Tried to create an **if...else** using **Eval** within ItemTemplate but unsuccessful.  Error message states:

> The server tag is not well formed.

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Paid" SortExpression="Paid">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="paidLBL" Text="<%# Eval("Paid") == "Y" ? "Yes" : "No" %>"></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: try this   Text='<%# Eval("Paid").ToString() == "Y" ? "Yes" : "No" %>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
Text='<%# Eval("Paid").ToString() == "Y" ? "Yes" : "No" %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

use `'` instead `"`

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="paidLBL" Text='<%# Eval("Paid") == "Y" ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: You and Piyush are totally correct to use `'` instead of `"`.  Thanks Rohit.

Comment: the same answer given before?Isn't